# Return rows which have values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which records the number of times a user logs into a page, but I am trying to filter out where the user has logged in at least twice throughout the week

Here is the table below

| User | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 15 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 20 |
| C | 18 | 1 | 0 | 18 | 1 | 38 |
| D | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Here is my expected output

| User | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 15 |
| C | 18 | 1 | 0 | 18 | 1 | 38 |

Comment: What do you mean filter out... you're showing the ones having at least 2 days of login.  Do you mean only show those having at least 2 days of login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a where clause case expression to evaluate each day for value > 0 and then sum the total >=2.  Each day must be evaluated on its own merit so we can not do simple math and divide or something.  Leaving us to evaluate each day independently.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE case when Monday > 0  then 1 else 0 end 
    + case when Tuesday > 0 then 1 else 0 end  
    + case when Wednesday > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
    + case when Thrusday > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
    + case when Friday > 0 then 1 else 0 end >=2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest below approach

```
select * from your_table t
where array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), ':0')) < 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]